# Python MySQL parameter queries for dynamic table names

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to query MySQL tables using my python program. However, the tables that I want to query are the ones whose names are passed in as variables (parameters).

I tried something like this:

```
readTable_query = """SELECT * FROM %s"""
readTable_cursor.execute(readTable_query, (table_name))
```

The problem with this is that the dynamically generated SQL query is putting the table name in quotes, i.e. instead of generating a query like "SELECT * FROM products", its generating a query like "SELECT * FROM 'products'". This is causing my program to fail and throws errors. Is there a workaround?

I know I could concatenate the query but that would lead to a security risk of SQL injection.

Full code for reference:

```
import MySQLdb

table_name = 'products'

db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,passwd,db)
readTable_cursor = db_connection.cursor() 
readTable_query = """SELECT * FROM %s"""
readTable_cursor.execute(readTable_query, (table_name))
```

Comment: In general, SQL parameterization usually doesn't allow parameterized tables (the thought being that allowing tables to be specified by user input _at all_ is so dangerous that validating that user input is just false security). In particular, Python's SQL parameterization is defined by the DB-API 2 spec, which doesn't allow table names. In even more particular, MySQLdb sort of does allow it, but it isn't documented and shouldn't be relied on. The right answer is usually to build a front-end view that lets you select a back-end table with a column value, then parameterize _that_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html , valid table names consist of the following characters. [0-9a-zA-Z_$]  So, it shouldn't be hard to write your own validator:

```
import re
table_name_validator = re.compile(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z_\$]+$')
if not table_name_validator.match(table_name):
    raise ValueError('Hey!  No SQL injecting allowed!')
```